# Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, quill

I've needed to display an alert in case there's a text input includes a double-quote which isn't followed by a backslash. So I used 'negative lookbehind' regular expression and achieved that goal.

```
text.innerHTML.match(/(?<!\\)\"/);
```

" -> Alert 
\" -> OK

However, I found an issue that when users put an indent into text box, the WYSIWYG (Quill) generates a class named "ql-indent-N (indent level starting from 1)" which triggers an alert by " detection.

Thus, I added another exception to the original regular expression like below.

```
text.innerHTML.match(/(?<!\\)(?<!class=)\"/);
```

But it didn't work so I tried some tests in console, and saw that

it works fine when I just put
class="
 -> OK

while, it does not work when it's inside real tag like 
<p class="ql-indent-1"> text </p>
 -> Alert

How can I make a lookbehind reg exp working fine with those <p class=" ...">? Or any other generous suggestion to achieve the same goal — Displaying an alert to double-quotes not followed by a backslash nor by <p class=" ...">? Below is a basic structure of the textbox.

```
<div class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true">
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

Dealing Quill's delta format is very complicated.

Comment: What if you check `element.innerText.match()` instead of checking `element.innerHTML.match()`, in order to ignore any tag added by the editor; would it be a viable solution?

Comment: It works! My limited knowledge over the script took time to find the right approach and you finally helped it out. I appreciate you @secan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you could refer to the element `innerText` rather than its `innerHTML` in order to ignore any tag inserted by the WYSIWYG editor.

Example (here I am using [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) rather than `RegExp.prototype.match()`)

```js
const qEditor = document.querySelector('.ql-editor');
const re = /(?<!\\)"/gm;

qEditor.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (re.test(qEditor.innerText)){
    window.alert('All double-quotes (") must be escaped (\\")');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="editor" class="ql-editor" data-gramm="false" contenteditable="true">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    theme: 'snow'
  });
</script>
```